# Select 2 audio files then play them in sequence afterwards, how to do?

Tags: jquery, deferred

I've got a problem working out how to get two audio files to play sequentially, after both of them have been selected, like select a.ogg, select b.ogg, play a.ogg then b.ogg. Selecting and playing one file at a time, like select a.ogg, play, select b.ogg, play, is handled by this code (mentioned elsewhere in stackoverflow):

```
 var audioIsPlaying = false;
 jQuery("div#word_set").click(function (evnt) {
   if(audioIsPlaying !== true) {
     var elementId = evnt.target.id;
     var pathVar = document.getElementById("pathVar").innerHTML;
     var oggVar = pathVar+elementId+".ogg";
     var audioElement = document.createElement("audio");
     audioElement.setAttribute("src", oggVar);    
     audioElement.play();
     audioIsPlaying = true;
     audioElement.addEventListener("ended", function() {
       audioIsPlaying = false;    
     });
    };
  });
```

I've looked at the jquery deferred object and its methods, done, resolve etc, but I'm not sure how to change the above code (if that is the way to go) to do what I want. Can the callback function in addEventListener be used to play the second audio file? Please pardon my ignorance, I'm on a steep learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

In this code snippet that you have provided, what you are doing is having a button click create an `<audio>` element and add the source of an audio file to it, but you are never setting up the second audio file to be played. Additionally, the `<audio>` should load the source before playing it, by adding the line `audioElement.load();` before `audioElement.play()`. You are going to have to create another function that sets up the `<audio>` element you just created to grab the source of the second audio file and load that and play it which should go in the eventListener function you created for when the first audio is done playing. If you post the whole code in a jsfiddle and provide the two files, I may be able to help you if you have any trouble.

Comment: I loaded the html, css and js files into jsfiddle and ran them but I can't see how to save. My user name for jsfiddle is mamboze. Maybe that'll help. The jsfiddle ui is a bit obscure (for me, anyhow) and the docos are not a lot better. Sorry about that, if you have any suggestions please let me know. Thank you for taking an interest, I appreciate it.

Comment: First of all, you need to capitalize `localStorage` properly, and also `getItem()` and `setItem()`, you didn't do camelcase at all. Furthermore, The fiddle doesn't have any audio file in it all...so how do you expect one to be played? Lastly, in the click functions, you spelled `event` incorrectly, instead of `evnt` it should be `event`. You need to get an audio file source in there somehow...

Comment: OK, capitalization done. There doesn't seem to be any way (not obvious, anyhow) to get audio files onto jsfiddle. I checked out the audio pages on jsfiddle and they access external audio files from online pages. I couldn't see any other way of doing it. I'll have to look for a hosting site. I think.

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You could just try this on a computer for the time being, and just load the audio files from an assets folder until you get the site done and ready to go live..